# "Convenient for you" vs "convenient to you"

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions

Is there a difference between "convenient for you" and "convenient to you"? And if it is, could you explain it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As well as the most common sense of *convenient* (i.e. suiting you, not causing you time or trouble), there is the related sense of *close, near-by*, as in "*We stopped at a convenient gas-station*" or "*He picked up a convenient rock*". While the phrase *convenient for you* is much the more common of the two, it could be that *convenient to you* is more likely to be used with this second sense.

Here are some examples from a quick search:

- Call the office most convenient to you.
- Choose a venue convenient to you.
- Kindly select a branch convenient to you.
- Visit our contact page to find a location that is convenient to you.
- Find a kitchen centre most convenient to you.

Comment: I dispute that "for you" is more common. This appears to be true when comparing the two three-word phrases on NGram, but that will include irrelevant things like *"It will be convenient for you to [do something]"*, where there's an implied *"convenient to us"*. But *"a time convenient to you"* is [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+time+convenient+for+you%2Ca+time+convenient+to+you&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *"a time convenient for you"*, and I don't think there will be many "false positives" with that wording

Comment: The impersonal expression *it is convenient for you* is 10 times more common (151,000) in Bing than *it is convenient to you* (15,000). The corresponding negative expressions have similar proportions: *for* - 4,000 as against *to* - a mere 13. However, when *convenient* is preceded by a noun, the reverse seems to be the case, although the numbers are much closer together. *Location, date, time* + *convenient* + *to* are more common than the same expressions with *for*. So in general it seems that *to* is much more likely with *convenient* following a noun than in an impersonal expression.

Comment: Interestingly, though, *a place convenient for you* is 4 times more common than *a place convenient to you*.

Answer (score 9):

While Answer 1 is the correct choice when the word "convenient' is related to location, using the word *to* doesn't apply as absolutely when the meeting's time is under negotiation.

To illustrate:

It works to say "convenient *to* you," when you're suggesting that a location can be  reached with little effort, like "near *to* you" or "next *to* you." This ruling is reinforced by the impossibility of saying "near *for* you" or "next *for* you."

But if the matter of discussion is an activity where time is the dominant question it offers enhanced clarity to suggest that to someone that they join in at a time that is more "convenient *for* you," even though *to* is technically OK.

Comment: This is the best answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research on this one, too, because both sound right, but according to an English teacher, who is also a Youtuber, you use 'to you' in reference to a location, whereas 'for you' is for the benefit as a result.

Talking *to you* is saying something to you, while talking *for you* is talking on behalf of you.

You can actually search for it in Youtube. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Lorane. welcome to EL&U. Your answer has already been posted by another user and doesn't provide any additional information. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Why not answer other new questions?